# Python: ¿Cómo puede realizar un producto escalar de las listas que actúan como elemento de una matriz con las filas de otra matriz?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Imaginad que tengo una matriz de tamaño (3, 3, 2) y otra matriz de tamaño (3 , 2). Mi duda es cómo puedo realizar un producto escalar para acabar teniendo una matriz de tamaño (3, 2). El problema lo podría resolver con un bucle for y hacer `np.dot` a mano, pero supongo que habrá una manera más sencilla (y más optima) de hacerlo.

Un ejemplo sería:

```
m1 = np.array([ [ [1,2],[0,2] ], [ [3,5],[2,2] ], [ [1,5],[4,1] ] ])
m2 = np.array([ [2,2],[1,3],[2,1] ])
```

Y acabar teniendo una matriz igual a:

```
m3 = np.array([ [6,4],[18,8],[7,9] ])
```

Donde

```
m3[0,0] = np.dot(m1[0,0],m2[0]) # 6 = 1*2+2*2
m3[0,1] = np.dot(m1[0,1],m2[0]) # 4 = 0*2+2*2
m3[1,0] = np.dot(m1[1,0],m2[1]) # 18 = 3*1+5*3
m3[1,1] = np.dot(m1[1,1],m2[1]) # 8 = 2*1+2*3
m3[2,0] = np.dot(m1[2,0],m2[2]) # 7 = 1*2+5*1
m3[2,1] = np.dot(m1[2,1],m2[2]) # 9 = 4*2+1*1
```

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La operación que quieres hacer puede expresarse como:

> Cada elemento `[i,j]` del resultado se computa mediante un sumatorio de los productos de los elementos `m1[i,j,k]` por `m2[i,k]` variando la `k`.

Matemáticamente:

[image: Formula]

Esto se puede expresar con la [notación de Einstein](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convenio_de_suma_de_Einstein) como "ijk,ik->ij"

Numpy soporta el cálculo de operaciones matriciales, vectoriales o tensoriales complejas, dada una cadena con la notación de Einstein, mediante la función `np.einsum()`, que en este caso se usaría por tanto así:

```
import numpy as np
m1 = np.array([ [ [1,2],[0,2] ], [ [3,5],[2,2] ], [ [1,5],[4,1] ] ])
m2 = np.array([ [2,2],[1,3],[2,1] ])

m3 = np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij', m1, m2)
```

El resultado es:

```
array([[ 6,  4],
       [18,  8],
       [ 7,  9]])
```

Exactamente el mismo que el que producen tus cálculos "manuales".

Comment: muchísimas gracias!